# How to listen to lose focus event of a part in Eclipse E4 RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I have multiple views in a perspective, these are shown as tabs. I want to catch the event when I switch from one `Part` to another (by clicking on the other parts tab). In other words I want to catch the event when a part looses focus. How can I do that in E4?

I have tried `IPartListener` implementation but its methods are called twice and also too late. For example, if I have parts A and B and part A is in focus, when I click on tab for part B, the `@Focus` method of part B is called first and then part deactivated (or part hidden) method of `IPartListener` is called for part A. I do not want that. Also, I have noticed that the `partActivated` and `partDeactivated` methods are called twice (for each part), which is also not desireable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jehan

Comment: I don't see any annotations called `@PartActivated` or `@PartDeactivated` in e4.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, these are not annotations, they are methods of `IPartListener` implementation.

Comment: I don't see partActivated being called twice in my app.

Comment: Ok. But for me it is called twice, however this is not such an important issue. The main thing is calling order of part deactivation and `@Focus`. Is there are way to capture event 'onclick' on tab of a part?

Comment: What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to ask the user if he wants to save the changes (if the part he is leaving is dirty). The user has 3 options: 1) save changes and switch to other part, 2) don't save changes but still switch to the other part and 3) cancel and don't leave the current part.

Comment: If you actually want to stop the part switch you will probably have to do a custom part stack renderer

Comment: Even implementing the custom part stack renderer only gives me control to activate() method.. nothing else useful...